# Backup and Restore Disaster Recovery

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, powershell, disaster-recovery

I am using PowerShell to write a script for DR, assuming that we only have backup files of all the databases. If i have a latest sql server version and i want to restore some database from backup files to this new target server, do i need to use -RelocateFile parameter of Restore-SqlDatabase which i think is equivalent to MOVE in T-SQL?

Comment: Depends if the file location will be the same on the new server. Eg `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.90\MSSQL\Data\ ` on both servers.

Comment: By file location do you mean the physicalName that i get via FILELISTONLY?

Comment: Yes that's the one.

Answer (score 0):

I would use DBAtools module, the restore commands offer much more flexibility.